# How do I POST/PUT JSON to a REST API endpoint without specifying Content-Type: application/json header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am working on typical Spring Boot REST API project and I am trying to figure out why all my POST and PUT endpoints API are getting "Unsupported Media Type" error if I don't specify Content-Type: application/json header.(so, if I unchecked Content-Type: application/json header in Postman, I get this error and everything works fine if I check that.)

Do I need to specify? Are there any ways that I can make them work without Content-Type: application/json header?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes you definitely need to specify content type.

Comment: So, things are working fine in Postman when I test. But another team member who is also testing (the caller is axios in React) is telling me that every other POST in the entire application succeeds without explicitly specifying content type. It is one PUT, which is the only PUT in the API is giving him this error. (HTTP 500) 

[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<io.swagger.entity.XxxxxXX>

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `@RestController` for the controller and use the appropriate method like @GetMapping, @PostMapping to make this work. So, basically spring requires content type because the input could be anything.